# R Shiny: datatableoutput not displaying when placed inside tabItems

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

Either the tabItems or the datatableoutput is behaving strange on my side.
If I run the app with below code by commenting out the tabItems (as shown below), it shows me the table.
But, when I put the tabItems back into the code, it shows an empty screen in my browser. There is no error message at all.

Can anybody help me understand where the problem lies?

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    # tabItems(
      # tabItem(
tabName = "dashboard",
fluidRow(
  column(
    width = 8,
    align = "center",
    dataTableOutput("tbl_cars")
  )
)
      # )
    # )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) { 
  output$tbl_cars <- renderDataTable({
    datatable(mtcars)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

## sessionInfo() ##
locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=C.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C           LC_TIME=C.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=C.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=C.UTF-8   
 [6] LC_MESSAGES=C.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=C.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C              LC_ADDRESS=C           LC_TELEPHONE=C        
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=C.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C   

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] DT_0.19               shinydashboard_0.7.2  shiny_1.7.1          

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.7        rstudioapi_0.13   magrittr_2.0.1    xtable_1.8-4      R6_2.5.1          rlang_0.4.11     
 [7] fastmap_1.1.0     tools_4.1.1       cli_3.0.1         jquerylib_0.1.4   withr_2.4.2       crosstalk_1.1.1  
[13] htmltools_0.5.2   ellipsis_0.3.2    yaml_2.2.1        digest_0.6.28     fontawesome_0.2.2 lifecycle_1.0.1  
[19] crayon_1.4.1      later_1.3.0       htmlwidgets_1.5.4 sass_0.4.0        promises_1.2.0.1  cachem_1.0.6     
[25] mime_0.12         compiler_4.1.1    bslib_0.3.1       jsonlite_1.7.2    httpuv_1.6.3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define what the tab will be like e.g

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard"))
  )),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
     tabItem(
    tabName = "dashboard",
    fluidRow(
      column(
        width = 8,
        align = "center",
        dataTableOutput("tbl_cars")
      )
    )
    )
     )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) { 
  output$tbl_cars <- renderDataTable({
    datatable(mtcars)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```